# Hindi font not rending properly in PDF in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fonts, pdf-generation, hindi

I am generating a PDF when a form is submitted. The language into the PDF I am using is English and Hindi. The problem is the Hindi font is not rending properly.

I am using "Laravel 7", for pdf generation I am using "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6"," Laravel package. I have used UTF-8 encoding into my HTML. The Hindi text in the browser shows correct (see the screenshot below)...

[image]

Comment: Hi @Akash Mishra .. I am having the same problem here.. have you solved this problem ? .. seems like there is the issue with library